# nodejs memory leak : process usage increase more than heap

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, centos, openshift

I got some memory leak issue on my nodejs app executed by openshift docker soulution.

when I try to monitor memory usage using process rss, I found process memory increased over time.

I'm trying to catch memory usage in process heap but memwatch, heapdump module can't show anything.
npm module showed heap size, and diff that size is under 50mb.
but process memory is still increasing and it uses over 150mb.

I thought It caused application leak issue so I try --expose-gc and called global.gc() but never helped.

how can I see where the process use memory or
does nodejs use OS memory more than that's max heap size?
(I showed memory usage increased over 4GB)

I want to fix it or want to see how nodejs use that memory.

thanks for read & answer :)

[image]

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. I can't understand how memory usage can grow over 4.5GB, while heap size has NOT been increased (no max_old_space_size) so it should be around 1.8GB. Running nodejs 10.15.3 in a docker swarm.